# Consider the following single-qubit state on the Block sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

$$\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 0 \right> + {\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}} \left| 1\right>
$$

I need to find the coordinate  , and ϕ values of the quantum state.

Comment: Related : [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere).

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer already given by MKM, you should start of by showing that you can write your state as

$$\left|\varphi\right> = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}} \left|0\right> + \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \left| 1 \right>,$$

from which the answer follows almost trivially. It might be helpful to remember that in Quantum Mechanics, a state is only defined up to an overall multiplicative phase. In other words, the states $\left|\psi\right>$ an  $e^{i\delta}\left|\psi\right>$ are physically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact, that any state on the Bloch sphere is given by (see [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)):
$$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle} \ket\psi=\cos(\theta/2)\ket 0+e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)\ket 1$$
You just need to solve system of equations.

Comment: I know the bloch sphere state, but I can't solve this system of equations @MKM

Comment: I want to know what the angle theta and phi of the system above please, @Philip