# Plugging a global phase into an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, symmetry, quantum-optics

Cheers to everyone. I' ve got a serious doubt about the following: consider the annihilation operator $\hat a$. For practical reasons, I sometimes find useful redefining it in the following way : $\hat a' =\hat a e^{i \phi}$, with $\phi \in \mathbb R$. If I add a new global phase to each eigenstate of $\hat a^\dagger \hat a$, $| 1 \rangle \rightarrow | 1 \rangle e^{i \phi}, \quad | 2 \rangle \rightarrow | 2 \rangle e^{2 i \phi} \,\dots$, I have a new annihilation operator $\hat a'$ and a new equivalent Hilbert space.

Is this $\hat a'$ physically reliable? Consider the time evolution of a state with Hamiltonian $\mathcal H = \alpha \hat a + \alpha^* \hat a^\dagger$, with $\alpha \in \mathbb C$. With the transformation described above $\alpha$ can be considered to be real without loss of generality. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "physically reliable"?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. See comment below, I explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal H = \alpha \hat a + \alpha^* \hat a^\dagger\\
=\alpha e^{-i\phi}~\hat a' + (\alpha e^{-i\phi})^* \hat {a'}~^\dagger\\
\equiv \alpha'  \hat a' + (\alpha ')^* \hat {a'}~^\dagger.$$

Names, by themselves, cannot affect physical relevance. Arbitrary complex number coefficients present differently in the unprimed and primed representations, which amounts to a complex rotation. For given coefficients, fixed, there is a complex rotation to make them real. What's your point?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should explain myself. The hamiltonian on top can be used to perform various rotations over the bloch sphere of a two-level system, but by applying this transformation you reduce the rotations to reflection over the x axis. This means that to fully describe any rotation can be reduced to a so-called pi-shift. This is what I was wondering.

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/523320/66086) might be of use.   The primed and unprimed systems are completely equivalent. There is a real *α* for some direction, and a real *α*' for another.