# Determine the state $|\psi \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, wavefunction, probability

The question is:

> The angular momentum components of an atom prepared in the state $|\psi\rangle$ are measured and the following experimental probabilities are obtained:
> \begin{equation} P(+\hat{z}) = 1/2, P(−\hat{z}) = 1/2,
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> P(\hat{x}) = 3/4, P(−\hat{x}) = 1/4,
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> P(+\hat{y}) = 0.067, P(−\hat{y}) = 0.933.
> \end{equation}
> From this experimental data, determine the state $|\psi \rangle$. Note that in performing the measurements, the state $|\psi \rangle$ is prepared again and again.

My attempt:
$$
 P(+\hat{z}) = 1/2 = P(−\hat{z})
$$
$$
|\langle {\uparrow}_z|\psi\rangle|^2=1/2 =|\langle {\downarrow}_z|\psi\rangle|^2
$$
$$
|\psi \rangle =\alpha |{\uparrow}_z\rangle+ e^{iδb} \beta|{\downarrow}_z\rangle
$$
$$
|\langle {\uparrow}_z|\psi\rangle|= \alpha = 1/\sqrt(2).
$$
Similarly,
$$
|\langle {\downarrow}_z|\psi\rangle|= \beta = 1/\sqrt(2).
$$

However, I don't know how to find $e^{iδb}$ term. Could someone please give a hint?

Comment: Why haven't you used the rest of the information given to you?

Comment: @J.Murray can you give any hint on how to use the other information?

Comment: This isn't a homework help site, so you'll have to reframe your question in a more conceptual way to avoid it being closed.  That being said, you've used 1/3 of the information given to you, so I don't quite understand why you're not using the rest in exactly the same way.

Comment: @rand do the same thing, but with $\langle \uparrow_x|\psi\rangle$ etc... , you will just have to calculate overlaps such as $\langle \uparrow_x|\uparrow_z\rangle$ etcetera and you'll be done

Comment: @Qmechanic : IMO, this question must not be tagged as homework-and-exercises since it's a chance for users to learn about Bloch sphere, a  tool  beyond the narrow frame of an exercise. If you don't agree I'll change my answer to a hint removing the results or I'll delete it at all.

Comment: @Frobenius Very relatedly, it's an excellent way to introduce the concept of quantum tomography and to illustrate how the phases store the information about probabilities of non-commuting operators (non-commuting w.r.t. the operator in whose eigenbasis we are expanding).

Comment: @Dvij D.C. : Welcome. Very interesting.

Comment: It's not  good practice the "homework-and-exercises" tag to be removed by the OP of the question.

Comment: @rand : Yes, you are right. But as you see in my comment above I address my point of view to the moderator QMechanic. I did not delete the "homework-and-exercises" tag. For your information "homework-and-exercises" in PSE is not necessarily a homework and/or an exercise in a textbook or in examinations. It could concern even self-study. The moderator, if disagrees, could delete my answer as giving complete solution to a  "homework-and-exercises" type question that is considered as off-topic here.  Have a good day.

Comment: @Frobenius To clarify, I think the homework-and-exercises tag should stay because it is clearly a type of question that would fall under that category. Just that it should not be deleted because it is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REFERENCE : My answer here [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere/415228#415228)

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=$

Equation (24) in my answer above is

\begin{equation}
\vert\psi\rangle \boldsymbol{=}\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert u_3\rangle \boldsymbol{+} e^{i\phi_3}\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert d_3\rangle 
\tag{24}\label{24}
\end{equation}
where $\vert u_3\rangle ,\vert d_3\rangle $ are yours $|{\uparrow}_z\rangle,|{\downarrow}_z\rangle$ respectively.

From the given probabilities $P(+\hat{z}) = 1/2, P(−\hat{z}) = 1/2
$ the state lies on the "equator" of the Bloch sphere. So from Figure-01 in my REFERENCED answer $\theta_3=\pi/2$. The angle $\phi_3=\boldsymbol{-}\pi/3$ could be found from one only of the probabilities  $P(\hat{x}) = 3/4, P(−\hat{x}) = 1/4,P(+\hat{y}) = 0.067$, $P(−\hat{y}) = 0.933$ and Figure-02  in my REFERENCED answer.

Note : I suggest you to "study" the excellent @CR Drost's answer about the Bloch sphere in above link.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[See a 3d view of Figure-03 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0JzA.png)