# Finding $\theta$ and $\phi$ when qubit state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}[i ,1]^T$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, linear-algebra, bloch-sphere

Because we know the state of a qubit can be described as:
$$
|q\rangle=\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}|1\rangle\\\ \\
\theta, \phi \in \mathbb{R}
$$

How do I find the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ when the qubit is in the state below?
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}i\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

What I've done so far:

$$
|q\rangle = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle
$$
Therefore
$$
\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\\
e^{i\phi}\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

But I don't know where to go from here. Could anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: I assume $\phi,\theta$ are real. The representation in your first formula allows only real coefficients for $|0\rangle$ but we know that $|q\rangle$ can be multiplied by a phase $e^{ia}$ without changing the physics.

Comment: Related : [Determine the state  $|\psi\rangle$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592131/determine-the-state-psi-rangle/592335#592335).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameterization assumes we rescale $|q\rangle$ by a unit complex factor so $\langle q|0\rangle\ge0$. In this case, you need to multiply by $-i$ first. So you actually want to solve $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\,e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}$. I leave you to solve that.

Edit: in the comments below, @KurtG. has noted the alternative (which is to multiply $|q\rangle$ by $+i$)
$$\tfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle=i\cos\tfrac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+ie^{i\phi}\sin\tfrac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle,$$
which works the same way.

Comment: So I know that means $\phi = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Could you explain your first sentence a bit more?

Comment: @HenryHudson . Unit complex factor is the phase $e^{ia}$ you are free to multiply your $|q\rangle$ with before solving for $\phi$ and $\theta$. Use a phase that makes the first component of $|q\rangle$ purely imaginary instead of real.

Comment: @HenryHudson Put differently: your vector $|q\rangle$ (in the first equation) cannot be equal to $[i,1]^T$ simply because $\langle 0|q\rangle \in \mathbb R$ and thus $\neq i$, for all $\theta$...

Comment: @KurtG. Why should I make the first component of $|q\rangle$ imaginary? My understanding by first component is the component of $|0\rangle$.

Comment: @HenryHudson I think the suggestion was to write your original $|q\rangle$ as $e^{i\alpha}$ times your Ansatz. Edit: as of the comment below, that is indeed the suggestion.

Comment: Because we know that there is no real $\theta$ that solves $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$. You will have more luck when you try to solve $i\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Okay, so I have $|q\rangle = e^{i\phi}\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$ which equals (when $\phi = -\frac{\pi}{2}$) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$. Then I can solve for $\theta$ as I already know $\phi = -\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @HenryHudson I've updated my answer to show how it works, as you've not quite done it right.