# Quantum state from probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, probability, quantum-states

Is it possible to determine a quantum state given the probabilities of +/- in the x and y components.

For example, a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ has the following probabailites:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
|\langle +_x|\psi\rangle|^2=p(ℏ/2) = 0.7 \\
|\langle -_x|\psi\rangle|^2=p(-ℏ/2) = 0.3
\end{cases} \ \text{and} \
\begin{cases}
|\langle +_y|\psi\rangle|^2=p(ℏ/2) = 0.2 \\
|\langle -_y|\psi\rangle|^2=p(-ℏ/2) = 0.8
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is entirely unclear.  What system are we talking about?  What does $x+$ refer to?

Comment: Are you familiar with [mixed states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states)?

Comment: In case that your question concerns a two-state system then you must give $P(+\hat{z}) , P(−\hat{z}) = 1-P(+\hat{z})$ also.See my answer here [Determine the state  $|\psi\rangle$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592131/determine-the-state-psi-rangle/592335#592335).

Comment: @Frobenius Hey would you care reviewing the second part of my answer? It's something I came up during the answer, seems correct to me, but I have not seen it previously anywhere, thanks for your time mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about pure state, and assuming you mean, that you have lots of identical states which you can try against x and y [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) as much times as you want, and those are the probabilities from the limit of doing infinite experiments with different copies of the same original state, then:

From those probabilities, you know that the original state has to be proportional to:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\sqrt{3}|+_x\rangle + e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2}|-_x\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left(\sqrt{3}(|+_z\rangle + |-_z\rangle)  + e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2}(|+_z\rangle - |-_z\rangle)\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(|+_y\rangle + e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4}|-_y\rangle\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left((|+_z\rangle + i |-_z\rangle)  + e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4}(|+_z\rangle -i |-_z\rangle)\right)
\end{equation}

where we have substituted the eigenvectors of the x and y [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Now we just need to write the + and - components of the z together and compare:

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left( (\sqrt{3}+e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2} )|+_z\rangle + (\sqrt{3}-e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2} )|-_z\rangle\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left( (1+e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4} )|+_z\rangle + i(1-e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4} )|-_z\rangle\right)
\end{equation}

where now we can do a system of equations and see if it is solvable deterministic or not:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{3}+e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2} = 1+e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4} \\
\sqrt{3}-e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2} = i(1-e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4})
\end{cases} \ \xrightarrow[]{} \
\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{3} = (1+i) + (1-i) e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4} \\
2e^{i\theta_1}\sqrt{2} = (1-i) + (1+i) e^{i\theta_2}\sqrt{4}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

from where it is pretty easy to find that for this case $\theta_2$ has to fulfill:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2\sqrt{3} - (1+i)}{\sqrt{4}(1-i)} = e^{i\theta_2}
\end{equation}
which is imposible, because the left part doesn't have modulus 1.

---

This does not mean, that you can't find a state from given probabilities, it just simply states that the probabilities you gave, can't really be happening.

In general you if you have a state with probability a of $+_x$, your state then can be found in a circle in the x axis in the bloch sphere, so considering both $+_x$ and $+_y$ probablities your state should be in both of those circles at the same time, which for your concrete example can't happen because the circles are too small:

[image]

But for another case, you would have one or two solutions (yellow dots), such as in this example:
[image]

This can be easily seen by, picking the x circle of 0 radius, which means our state is exactly $|+_x\rangle$ or $|-_x\rangle$, then the only possibility for the y circle would be a maximum radius one, which mean 1/2 probability of $+_y$ or $-_y$:

[image]

such as we know the eigen states of x have.