# 90 degree rotation about $z$-axis on Bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

I am a beginner on quantum information and right now I study it from the lectures by Peter Shor. The lectures can be found on [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-information-science-i-part-1) and can be viewed on YouTube as well.

The lecture that I'm struggling to understand is one in which Shor's explain about continuous rotation on the Bloch sphere. [Near the end of the lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyUBMhKz1nQ&t=187s), the Prof. gives an example that the rotational matrix $e^{-i\theta \sigma_z/2}$ can be used to rotates by 90 degree from the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)$. [A few seconds later](https://youtu.be/CyUBMhKz1nQ?t=207), he substitutes $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ into the formula of rotational matrix. It's here that confused me. Why $\frac{\pi}{4}$? It looks wrong because, when multiplying the matrix with $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$, the result isn't  $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: there's a factor of 1/2 in the exponent

Comment: Related : [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere/415228#415228). Especially CR Drost's answer.