# On change representation of spin 1/2 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, commutator

Suppose I find a $1/2$ spin particle in the eigenstate of the observable $\hat S_x$ relative to the eigenvalue $\hbar / 2$. I will use the short-hand notation $ \vert \uparrow_x \rangle$.

The goal is to express it in terms of the eigenstates of the observable $\hat S_z$: $\{ \vert \uparrow_z \rangle, \vert \downarrow_z \rangle\}$.

I have to solve the linear system:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 &\vert \uparrow_x \rangle = \alpha  \vert \uparrow_z \rangle + \beta  \vert \downarrow_z \rangle \\
 &\vert \downarrow_x \rangle = \alpha'  \vert \uparrow_z\rangle + \beta'  \vert \downarrow_z \rangle
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

The condition of normalization $\langle \uparrow_x \vert \uparrow_x \rangle = \langle \downarrow_x \vert \downarrow_x \rangle = 1$ returns $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = |\alpha'|^2 + |\beta'|^2 = 1 $, while the ortogonality, $\langle \uparrow_x \vert \downarrow_x \rangle = \langle \downarrow_x \vert \uparrow_x \rangle = 0$ implies $\bar{\alpha}\alpha' + \bar{\beta}\beta' = \bar{\alpha}'\alpha + \bar{\beta}'\beta =   0$.

Now, here comes the problem.
Using the identity $[S_+, S_-] = 2 \hbar S_z$ I could write
$$
[S_+, S_-]\vert \uparrow_x \rangle = 2 \hbar S_z \vert \uparrow_x \rangle
$$
expanding the commutator
$$
\begin{aligned}
(S_+S_- - \require{cancel}\cancel{S_-S_+}) \vert \uparrow_x \rangle = \hbar ^2 \vert \uparrow_x \rangle 
\end{aligned}
$$
I end up with
$$\frac{\hbar}{2}\vert \uparrow_x \rangle = S_x\vert \uparrow_x \rangle = S_z\vert \uparrow_x \rangle $$

But it *can't* be! I have been checking it for quite a while, but I still don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Maybe $\hat S_+$ vanishes only with $\vert \uparrow_z \rangle $, but I'm not sure

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I think it's the same subspace, represented by different bases.  They are not orthogonal one another

Comment: Related : [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere). The space of states of a spin-1/2 particle is a Hilbert space. Each one of the sets $\{\vert \uparrow_z \rangle,\vert \downarrow_z \rangle\}$,$\{\vert \uparrow_y \rangle,\vert \downarrow_y \rangle\}$, $\{\vert \uparrow_x \rangle,\vert \downarrow_x \rangle\}$ is an orthonormal (eigen)basis. See equation (25) and Figure-04 in my answer in above link.

Comment: @Vladimir Kalitvianski : I apologize, but I must say that you have a very very wrong view about the Hilbert space  of states of a spin-1/2 particle. I am not an expert but I suggest you to correct this view in order to avoid confusion about this stuff in the future.

Comment: I am stuck. What the relation between the 10 years-8 months user therein [Vladimir Kalitvianski](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1390/vladimir-kalitvianski) and the 3 months user herein [Vladimir Kalitvianski](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/301137/vladimir-kalitvianski) ???

Comment: @Frobenius: I am both of them, just seen from different computers.

Comment: @Vladimir Kalitvianski : Thanks for the clarification. I got stuck because your comments about  the Hilbert space of states of a spin-1/2 particle do not match the level of the 10 years-8 months user (Theoretical Physicist) we meet in answers herein.

Comment: I was wrong, but never mind - I am a bad user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing properties that are defined for $|\uparrow_z\rangle $ with those defined for  $|\uparrow_x\rangle $.
The right relations are
$$S_z|\uparrow_z\rangle  = \frac\hbar2 |\uparrow_z\rangle;$$
$$S_z|\downarrow_z\rangle  = -\frac\hbar2 |\downarrow_z\rangle,$$
and thus
$$S_z|\uparrow_x\rangle  = \alpha\frac\hbar2 |\uparrow_z\rangle-\beta \frac\hbar2 |\downarrow_z\rangle .$$

The other one that is wrong is that you assumed $S_+|\uparrow_x\rangle =0$ which is not, the right condition is $S_+|\uparrow_z\rangle =0$ and $S_+|\downarrow_z\rangle =\hbar|\uparrow_z\rangle$ . Which leads to

$$S_+|\uparrow_x\rangle= \cancel{\alpha S_+|\uparrow_z\rangle} +\beta S_+|\downarrow_z\rangle=\beta\hbar|\uparrow_z\rangle.$$
The rest you can work it out if you work only on the $|\updownarrow_z\rangle$ basis.