# Directly get tangent vector of Bloch sphere from quantum state (qubit)?

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

We know that Bloch sphere is a good way to represent a qubit(two energy quantum systems). Now I want to know the tangent vector in Bloch sphere, e.g. for states $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 1\\
 e^{i\varphi}\\
\end{array} \right) $, or equivalently with $x,y,z$ coordinate:$\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \cos\varphi\\
 \sin\varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) $. We can calculate the tangent vector by $\partial _{\varphi}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \cos\varphi\\
 \sin\varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -\sin\varphi\\
 \cos\varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) $.

My question is, is there a way to calculate a quantity similar to $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 -\sin\varphi\\
 \cos\varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) $ without refer to $x,y,z$ coordinates? Because I want to see what the tangent vector correspond to $n$-qubits instead of single qubit case, in that case, we can't seek help from $x,y,z$ coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by "tangent vector"? Tangent to *what*?

Comment: are you asking how to compute a basis of tangent vectors to a (point on a) sphere in general? That's doable, but note that in higher dimensions the "Bloch representation" of quantum states won't look like a (hyper)sphere. See e.g. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24422/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8416/55, and links therein

Comment: @glS Thanks for the refs. I just don't quit understand how $\partial _{\varphi}\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \cos \varphi\\
 \sin \varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) $ can be connected with $\partial _{\varphi}|\psi _{\varphi}\rangle $, where $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \cos \varphi\\
 \sin \varphi\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right) $ is the bloch vector of $|\psi _{\varphi}\rangle $.

Comment: Related : My answer here [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere). I know nothing about Quantum Computation but as you could see in my answer a state on the Bloch sphere may be represented by
$$
\vert\psi\rangle =\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert u_3\rangle + e^{i\phi_3}\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert d_3\rangle
$$

Comment: A unit vector tangent to the sphere (in the sense that it will be orthogonal to $\vert\psi\rangle$) could be produced  by differentiation with respect to $\theta_3$
$$
\vert\chi_\theta\rangle=2\dfrac{\partial \vert\psi\rangle}{\partial \theta_3} =-\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert u_3\rangle + e^{i\phi_3}\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert d_3\rangle
$$
represented by a point diametrically opposite to that of $\vert\psi\rangle$.

Comment: But differentiation with respect to $\phi_3$ doesn't produce a vector orthogonal to $\vert\psi\rangle$
$$
\vert\chi_\phi\rangle=\dfrac{\partial \vert\psi\rangle}{\partial \phi_3}=\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert u_3\rangle + i\,e^{i\phi_3}\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta_3}{2}\right)\vert d_3\rangle
$$
so not tangent to the sphere in above sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the crucial point is that why we could represent a qubit by a sphere is that they could be represented as coherent state: any state is just
$e^{i\hat{n}\cdot S}\left|\uparrow\right\rangle_z$, when as a qubit you choose $S_i=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i$ to be Pauli matrix and $\left|\uparrow\right\rangle_z=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\end{array}\right)$and as a vector you choose $\left|\uparrow\right\rangle_z=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 0\\0\end{array}\right)$ and $S$ the generator of rotating vectors -- the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ is the same as $SO(3)$, which means that the commutation relation of $S_i$ in these two cases are the same. Thus when you calculate $\partial_\varphi |\psi\rangle$ in the two case, treat $S$ as some abstract operators with commutation relation and finally put its true form back. Thus the result should be the same.

Comment: Can you give some concrete example? I can't quite understand...