# 3 Eigenstates for $X$?

Tags: quantum-information

Unless I have made an error, the Pauli $X$ operator has 3 eigenstates. [Qiskit](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-states/single-qubit-gates) lists the two eigenstates for $X:|+\rangle= \frac 1{\sqrt2}(|1\rangle + |0\rangle)$ and $|-\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle -|1\rangle$. Attempting to prove this myself, I did the work behind finding eigenstates with $\lambda=\pm1$, found from finding the determinant: $$\det(X-\lambda I)$$ Yet, I found that there were two possible solutions for the eigenstate correlated with eigenvalue $-1$. 
Assuming that we know our eigenvalues, we find eigenstates of $X$ through the form: 
$$(X-\lambda I)\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0-\lambda&1\\1&0-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$.
When $\lambda=1$, our eigenstate is $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$, or $|+\rangle$.
But when $\lambda=-1$, we are left with $x_1 + x_2 =0$, meaning that either $x_1$ or $x_2$ can be $-1$. This leaves our eigenvalue of $\lambda = -1$ having eigenstate of both  $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$, or  $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|1\rangle - |0\rangle)$. This is problematic considering that the $X$ basis of measurement is based on the eigenstates of $X: |+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$. Please help me understand this dilemma. Thank you.

Comment: Related : [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that states differing by a global phase are physically equivalent. The two states mentioned differ by a global factor of $-1$.

By the same token, one can find other eigenstates with eigenvalue $+1$ such as $(-|0\rangle-|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Was just about to write this as a comment under the main question, but maybe another way of saying this is that a [scalar multiple of an eigenstate is also another eigenstate with the same eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557665/is-the-scalar-multiple-of-an-eigenvector-also-an-eigenvector-for-a-particular-ei)

Comment: @ZadeJohnston absolutely

Comment: I see my error now; it appears as though I missed that basic fact. Thanks much!